# Does each reactor run in it's own thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, reactor, resource-leak

Profiling my twisted app I am seeing that `twisted/application/app.py:startReactor` was called 496 times. Apart of this, I am seeing thread leaking: ~500 threads were created by the app, most of them are idle in `FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE`. During this profiling simple load test were run: ~1rps.

Does it mean that somewhere in the code `reactor.run()` is leaking? Where should I start digging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.  `reactor.run` does not start a thread.  However, if you have an application that starts 496 reactors then maybe *it* starts threads in which to run each of them.

Comment: I suspect that my app creates too many reactors and each reactor has it's own  poolthreads for db and http clients. I see in my theseus profiler that `scripts/twistd.py:run` was called 5 380 times. What can it mean?

Comment: It means that scripts/twistd.py:run was called 5380 times I suppose.  I can't really say any more without seeing the code you're asking about.  It could be doing ... literally ... anything.